# Using Laravel pagination with Twig templates

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, twig

I'm using TwigBridge package (`barryvdh/laravel-twigbridge`) with Laravel. Everything was working fine but when I tried to use a Twig template to render pagination links raw HTML was outputted. I wrote the `links` call as following:

```
{{ users.links('includes.paginate') }}
```

And I have a template file at `app/views/includes/paginate.twig`.

There is some configuration that I have to change or add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that package (I use rcrowe's one), but [looking at its config](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-twigbridge/blob/master/src/config/config.php) file I see:

```
 'options' => array(

    'autoescape' => 'html',

 )

* autoescape: Whether to enable auto-escaping (default to html):
| * false: disable auto-escaping
| * true: equivalent to html
| * html, js: set the autoescaping to one of the supported strategies
| * PHP callback: a PHP callback that returns an escaping strategy based on the template "filename"
```

A bad solution would be to turn off autoescaping, but that would be global and it might affect your app in ways you won't like. Did you try using the [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) Twig filter?

```
{{ users.links('includes.paginate')|raw }}
```

Comment: Worked with `raw` filter! Thank you!